# How to process a String input including single quotation

Tags: python

I wrote a script by python which prompts users to Enter a string, then encode or decode it.
However, one of the users Entered single quotation( this -> ' ) so the script stopped.
How can I solve this problem.
I would like to accept single quotation as an input.
the script looks like this:

```
while True:
    input = raw_input('Enter a word or sentence')
    if input == 'done':break
    n = raw_input('Enter an encode number')
    print encode(input,n) #this function encodes the input by n and returns encoded words
```

There are ord and chr function in the encode function.

this is encode function

```
def encode(word,n):
"""
word: strings you wanna encode or decode
n: a number you wanna encode or decode by
"""
code = 0
rotate = ''
for letter in word:
    if ord(letter) == ord(',') or ord(letter)== ord('.') or  ord(letter) == ord(' ') or ord(letter) == ord('?') or ord(letter) == ("'"):
        rotate += letter
        continue
    rotate += rotate_num(letter,n,letter.islower())
return rotate

def rotate_num(letter,n,lower):
"""
n: a number you wanna encode or decode by
lower:Assign True if the letter is lowercase, otherwiser False
"""
if lower:
    a = 'a'
    z = 'z'
else:
    a = 'A'
    z = 'Z'
code = ord(letter)+n
if code > ord(z):
    code = code - 1  - ord(z)+ ord(a)
if code < ord(a):
    code = ord(z) -   ( ord(a)-code-1)
return chr(code)
```

(the rotate_num function should be indented. I missed copying)

the problem was that the input was too long(He entered too long sentence). However, other problem remained:
in the encode function, I wrote: if the letter is a single quotation,
it should not be encoded,
but actually, the single quotation was encoded

Comment: The problem is in your encode function, please post that.

Comment: Can u post the encode function? as far as I tested, `input` is correct, whether there is a single quote or not.

Comment: I'm sorry to late to post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your encode() function, the last part of the if-statement checks for
ord(letter) == ("'"), which will never become True since [ord()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) return an Integer.

It should be ord(letter) == **ord**("'")

or simply check for letter == "'" (without calling ord)

Comment: actually, this(my) code isn't smart.
so I think I should rewrite like this:

    if letter in ',?\'" .':
        rotate += letter

Answer (score 1):

You could try using re.escape:

```
import re
re.escape(n)
```

However, I was not able to reproduce your issue. If the error is coming from the encode function, try making sure n is an int before you do things with it.